# What does 'R' mean in the context of string literals?

Tags: c++, string-literals

This code basically talks to a AMPS server and tries to publish a topic.

What is meaning of `R` in the second parameter of the `publish(`)?

```
#include <ampsplusplus.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    const char* uri = "tcp://127.0.0.1:9007/amps/json";

    // Construct a client with the name "examplePublisher".

    AMPS::Client ampsClient("examplePublisher");

    try
    {
        // connect to the server and log on
        ampsClient.connect(uri);
        ampsClient.logon();

        // publish a JSON message
        ampsClient.publish("messages",
                           R"({ "message" : "Hello, World!" ,)"
                           R"(client" : 1 })");

    }
    catch (const AMPS::AMPSException&amp; e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Since you're new, do you know what to do when [someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)? Also, while you're there, take a look at [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Thanks for the comment. I am new to the platform and hence did not know about attribution. Nevertheless, I shall edit the post and keep that in mind next time.
Also, I referred to the documentation. I did not find anything in regard to the 'R'. Next time, I shall dig deeper before posting query. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *prefix*(optional) `R "delimiter( raw_characters )delimiter"` (6) (since C++11)

[Raw string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). Used to avoid escaping of any character. Anything between the delimiters becomes part of the string. *prefix*, if present, has the same meaning as described above.

Example:

```
const char* s1 = R"foo(
Hello
World
)foo";
//same as
const char* s2 = "\nHello\nWorld\n";
```

where `foo` is the delimiter.

---

In your case, a `message` would print:

```
{ "message" : "Hello, World!" ,client" : 1 }
```

Comment: Looks like there is a missing `"` in front of `client`, but I can't know that for sure. It also seems most pretty-printers / code highlighters do *not* like this at all.

Comment: Yes.. There was a missing " before client.